# Django: language in field description in forms won't change

Tags: django, internationalization, django-forms

When I change language on my Django-powered site, everything works fine except the translation of the field descriptions in the forms. The description is still displayed in the old language. Only the forms already visited that session are affected.

It seems like some sort of caching problem, but I don't use any caching (as far as I know) and all other parts of the site behave as expected (templates and random text using django.utils.translaction.ugettext work just fine).

Summarized:

1. When I open the site and change language, and then visit a form: everything works as expected. All text is translated.
2. When I visit a form, change language and return to the form: everything is translated, but the form stays in the old language.
3. Restarting the web server forces the language to change: then Django behaves as in (1) for the current session. Until the language is changed again.

Help is appreciated!

Kind regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by changing

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext  as _
```

to

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy  as _
```

for my forms.